# How many downvotes is "enough"?

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes, voting, upvotes

[This is the lowest-scoring answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4797328/4356188)

Were all the downvotes necessary, though? A downvote says, "Hey, this answer is low-quality, not useful, and/or wrong." 5 - 10 downvotes would've been enough to communicate the message clearly.

Once a post gathers a high number of downvotes, further downvotes have diminishing returns. The answer is already at the bottom of the list (sorting by votes), grayed-out, and interactive snippets are disabled. The author already understands that their answer is wrong. All that casting another downvote does is charge you 1 rep point and take 2 rep points from the post author. There's really no good reason to downvote answers past -10, or perhaps -25.

**Should we refrain from downvoting answers that have a very low score?**

---

Related: [The "I Get It" Reputation Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/552/296278)

---

**TL;DR:** Of course you should downvote bad answers, but is it overkill at some point? When the community downvotes an answer past a reasonable level (such as -10), it doesn't really help to increase quality and helpful information anymore. All that does is penalize the author with reputation loss.

---

> *But the question doesn't ask for system imposed limits, it asks "Should we refrain". Wouldn't you expect the SQL injection answer to have a lower score than someone that mistyped a function name, if they both have the same number of views? If all readers downvote both posts, regardless of score, this won't happen... – user000001*

Views are the key. If Post A and Post B are equally bad, but Post A is viewed 10 times and Post B is viewed 100 times, Post B will have a score 10 times as low as Post A even though they're of the same quality.

Comment: Should we refrain from upvoting answers that have a very high score?

Comment: *"The answer is already sorted to the bottom of the list"* irrelevant as there are "active" and "oldest" sort methods, you should never justify your downvote as a means of sorting

Comment: @StephenRauch Yes. [Requests for putting rep caps on posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136059/296278) were never implemented despite community support for them. So why don't we CHOOSE to vote as if there's a rep cap per post?

Comment: @Memor-X Isn't a major part of the Stack Exchange model voting to sort the best answers on top and the worst on the bottom? Go to https://stackexchange.com/ in Incognito mode, and it says so right there in the top banner.

Comment: Why would we? If it's -10 but I find it bad I downvote. A bit of an extreme argument, but what if 10 people upvote that -10? If I decided that '-10 is enough' we now have a 0 answer. If I downvoted we still have a negative answer. To me, I vote based on if it's useful or not. I try to see the other votes as the Facebook 'reactions' on posts: showing me what others voted, but not what I necessarily feel. That's why I prefer to not think of such a limit and vote based on what I feel is correct, regardless of score

Comment: @sag *"The right answer. Right on top. ... so the most helpful answers are easy to find."* doesn't say anything about the score, if score was the only metric then we wouldn't have the other ordering methods for instance ordering by active can sometimes get you more up-to-date answers. the right answer depends on who's reading it anyway as if i saw an answer which was just a fixed code dump of the Asker's code i'd wouldn't call it the right answer even if the Asker accepts it because it does nothing to tell me how to fix the problem if i came across it with different code

Comment: [Not even 147 downvotes is enough for such a poor question...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly)

Comment: @DavyM you're looking at the net score. it as 217 downvotes (and 71 upvotes)

Answer (score -13, accepted):

Yes we should. If we only consider the content and not the score, then it means that the score of each post will be directly proportional to the number of views it got, and it won't say much about the actual quality.

On the contrary, if we want the score to be an indicator of quality (and not only popularity) we should consider if the score is higher or lower than what is appropriate for each specific post.

Answer (score 16):

No, we should not. We should only ever consider the content of a post when voting on posts.

Answer (score 11):

A response to one particular sentence which I am willingly going to yank out of context.

> All that does is punish the author with reputation loss.

False! Not only is a loss of reputation **not** any form of punishment, its just balancing of the books. But it's also not something that we as a site visitor are in any way responsible for either. We do not push buttons to give people reputation points or take them away. That's what the site's software does behind the scenes, business logic based on input. It is not a side effect of a bug either, it is specifically and intentionally programmed that way.

The only thing we do is vote on a *piece of content*. We use the feature as designed and intended, there are no limits because if there should be limits then those limits would be *built in*. What kind of side effects that has behind the scenes or how unfair that may or may not be has absolutely no bearing on how important it is that we keep voting, without question, without prejudice.

I don't think anything has to change at all given that it is easier to gain reputation than it is to lose reputation if you're even half serious about what you do; there is a shiny delete button that makes problems go away too. But hypothetically say that something does need to change because we all collectively agree that the way it works now is unfair - it is not that people should stop voting when a particular threshold is reached; it is that the site software should be more fair about how it gives and takes reputation points.

---

TL;DR If something needs to be changed it is the programming that manages reputation points, not the way we use the site. In other words: you solve the problem, you don't work around it.

Answer (score 9):

There is no way to fairly determine how many is enough. It's entirely subjective what would be enough and what is not, and therefore it's entirely fair to allow unlimited downvotes to happen to a natural maximum as decided on anyone who wants to state more is needed (they downvote) or it's enough (they don't downvote).
This is natural and fair.

I get your point, but when you think beyond the face value that 100+ downvotes for a trivial answer seems overkill, and step into thinking about making this a potential reality, there are so many problems that cannot be overcome.

> Were all the downvotes necessary, though?

What is "necessary"?

I haven't downvoted yet, so why would you block the voting? Are you saying the other 155 people can downvote but I cannot?

> 5 - 10 downvotes would've been enough to communicate the message clearly

Says who? Based on what criteria, and why? Is this just your own personal idea that 10 is enough? It's as entirely subjective to set a max downvote limit as are the reasons to downvote, and exactly why we cannot limit any of it.

How do you determine some threshold? The issue with that is you'd need different thresholds based on the content. For example:

> hey I love bananas

is stupid but harming no-one so do we make the limit 20 downvotes to signify this is not good? Or see that it's really not harming anything at all so let's just make it 5.

What about it reducing the overall quality of the site and makes the question hard to moderate, so should be a 35? To *really* ward off future would be banana loving activists.

Then what if someone is suggesting

> Just use that `$_GET` data directly in a raw `mysql_` query

This is *very* bad and we should allow 50 downvotes. That's a lot right?
Or, should we allow 200 to *really* signify the problem in the answer?

It's impossible to do this.

If some limit is 20 and user 21 wants to vote we're stopping them? Do we let them upvote though? We have to right, and then that means we need to allow one more downvote. This would be a very complicated system for no real gain.

Especially when you consider people can delete their answer at any point.

Even if we could agree on what deserves what max downvotes, how on Earth would be have an algorithm to identify each "type" of answer to limit it. And even ignoring that impossibility, imagine how immensely huge the database would be to store all the possible "types" and their relevant max downvotes.

Comment: But the question doesn't ask for system imposed limits, it asks "Should *we* refrain". Wouldn't you expect the SQL injection answer to have a lower score than someone that mistyped a function name, if they both have the same number of views? If all readers downvote both posts, regardless of score, this won't happen...

Comment: @user000001 "*But the question doesn't ask for system imposed limits*" How would you otherwise expect and enforce people not downvoting? How would you share the knowledge of when people should no longer downvote for them to manually not downvote? How would you clear up the huge amounts of grey areas? How would you enforce this?

Comment: No defining gray areas or enforcing is required, I read the post merely as a suggestion to potential voters.

Comment: @user000001 but that is already the case right now, people have free will to vote. So, I ask again, given people already have free will to vote, how do you change the "current" over voting as being discussed and get people to vote less?